# I18N with Express/Jade: Strings with embedded tags and interpolation

Tags: internationalization, express, template-engine, pug

tl;dr: I am looking for an elegant method of doing internationalization in Jade templates. Essentially the problem boils down to that I have to do interpolation on strings in variables, instead of verbatim code.

Problem details:

In a monolingual Jade template I can just make an element with embedded tags and variables like so:

```
p Posted by 
  span.author= post.author
  | on
  span.date= post.author
```

to get something like

```
<p>Posted by <span style="author">The Author</span> on 
<span style="date">2012-03-08</span></p>
```

But when I want to internationalize this, I need a single string, since word order is not the same in every language. Also, I would like to hide html details from translators, and just give them a line like this:

```
Posted by #{author} on #{date}
```

Now when I pass the i18n-ed version of this string to the Jade template as i18n.posted_by_on, it won't do interpolation on it, so the best I can do is:

```
- var author = '<span class="author">$</span>'.replace('$',post.author); 
- var date = '<span class="date">$</span>'.replace('$',post.date);
- var header = i18n.posted_by_on
      .replace('#{author}',author)
      .replace('#{date}',date); 
p!= header
```

This mostly defeats the point of the nice Jade templating, as I have to do all the interpolation manually. Is there any method doing it more nicely, compactly, readable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably found a solution by now (if so, please tell us what it is), but if you didn't, you might want to look at the [i18next-node](http://i18next.com/) library. It supports variables, so you could do things like:

```
// Localized resources
{           
  'en-GB': {
    translation: { 
        space_temperature_is: 'Space temperature is __COUNT__ degrees Celsius.'
     }
   }
  'fr-FR': {
    translation: { 
        space_temperature_is: 'Température de l'espace est de __COUNT__ degrés Celsius.'
     }
   }
};
```

Then, in your jade template, you would do:

```
// This translates to "Space temperature is 28 degrees Celsius."
i18n.t('space_temperature_is', { COUNT: 28 });
```

The library is really well documented, but, if you're in a hurry, here's [an article](http://rbeere.tumblr.com/post/41212250036/internationalization-with-express-jade-and) that I found useful as a quick introduction.

Comment: I never did find an answer (priorities shifted), but this seems to fit, so I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

As we can see it on the short doc, there is a sprinf style function
https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node
I think this would help you to achive you goal

Comment: Hi, excuse the slightly late :) reply. That tool doesn't seem to fit the bill because it uses positional arguments.